# python iterate multiple csv files into SQL table

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import urllib
import glob
import os
import re

path = r'D:\myfolder'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

li=[]

for filename in all_files:
    df_from_each_file = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None, error_bad_lines=False)
    li.append(df_from_each_file)


df= pd.concat(li, ignore_index=True)

search1="AreaID=*\d+"
search2="ExportID=*\d+"
df['AreaID']=df['cs-uri-query'].str.findall(search1, flags=re.I).str[-1]
repl1 = re.compile(r'AreaID=',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df['AreaID']=df['AreaID'].str.replace(repl1,'', regex=True).replace(np.NaN,0).astype(int)
df['ExportID']=df['cs-uri-query'].str.findall(search2, flags=re.I).str[-1]
repl2 = re.compile(r'ExportID=',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df['ExportID']=df['ExportID'].replace("ExportID=",'', regex=True).replace(np.NaN,0).astype(int)
df_4cols=df[['date','cs-username','AreaID','ExportID']]
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://iislogadmin:adlog@123@seskwtstecap01,1435/IISLogs?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server')
df_4cols.to_sql('traksyslogs', schema='dbo', con = engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

**I am trying to loop in multiple CSV files (around 150 files of total 10GB) and insert into SQL table. Wheni try to iterate with the following code, i am getting error. Should i ditch pandas and try to do in DASK? Pls help**

PS C:\Users\raj> python 'c:\myfolder\testsql.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\myfolder\testsql.py", line 22, in 
    df= pd.concat(li, ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 271, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 329, in **init**
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: You're on Windows, but you're using a *nix path separator here: `all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "/*.csv"))`. That should instead be: `all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))`

Comment: Yes i have changed that, but still iam facing the same error